# show the scroll bar when the content overflows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to apply an animation that looks this way:

The page loads and after one second there is a box shows up slowly from the bottom of the page, I achieved that with adding a class called `height` (that you see in my code below).

The problem is that box will have some content that will be input by the user so its height will be increased to be able to display all the content that the user input, but this is not what happens when the content passes the provided height (the height coming from the `height` class) the overflow content will be hidden.

I don't want that behaviour I want the scrolling bar to show up.

here is an executable snipet: https://codepen.io/Amoocris/pen/vPWOpX

```js
setTimeout(

  function() {
    document.querySelector(".plansBackground").classList.add("height");
  }, 1000

);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.backIMg {
  background-color: rgb(155, 230, 170);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.plansBackground {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 1s;
  color: black;
}

.height {
  height: 25vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div class="backIMg">


  <div class="plansBackground">
    <div class="Plans-container" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div class="background-extand">

        <h1 class="day">
          Monday
        </h1>

      </div>



    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add ti CSS

```
.plansBackground {
     overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/fyodor_e82/pen/vwoVWN)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, `overflow:visible` will act like `overflow:hidden` on absolutely positioned elements that are at the very bottom of the viewport/page. The simple solution is to give `overflow-y:auto` to `.height`.